# How to render multiple div background color change with div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

While onclick the div background color will change to blue again click the div color will change to white.. with dynamic id... please help how can I do in reactjs

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#my_checkbox').on('change',function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#card").css('background-color',"blue");
      }else{
        $("#card").css('background-color','white');
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Hey, you should not put reactjs tag. Because it's not a react question.

Comment: OP is asking how to accomplish the same thing using reactjs, so it is a reactjs question.

Comment: added solution @rout-prativa

Comment: hi I have multiple div whiles bind in classname it same time all div's colors are changed, so m trying with id, so onClick in div single div color will change with id based, please help

Answer (score 1):

In react you simply use the component state in 2 ways

Function Component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function SomePage() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>Click Me</button>
      <div style={{ color: toggle ? 'red' : 'blue' }}>my color is changed</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Class Component

```
import React from 'react'

class SomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      toggle: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ toggle: !toggle })}>Click Me</button>
        <div style={{ color: this.state.toggle ? 'red' : 'blue' }}>my color is changed</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

this is the basic level of react, you should adjust to your needs

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#my_checkbox').on('change',function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#card").css('background-color',"blue");
      }else{
        $("#card").css('background-color','white');
      }
    })
  })
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="card" style="height:300px;width:200px;">
 <input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```